# What is the data structure that represents message in Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, message

In ethereum whitepaper there are separate sections for [Transaction](https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#messages-and-transactions) and [Message](https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#messages) contents.
While I am able to find in an implementation a file called "transaction.go" which contains (more or less the same) fields mentioned in the whitepaper I cannot find such file for Message. Is the same data structure used for both (Transactions and Messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, the same data structure is used for both Transactions and messages.

The Transaction contains the message and the data field of the transaction represents the message

The `transaction.go` file contains a struct with the data field.

The data field has a representation of the transaction's messages

Empty data field = simple transaction

data field not empty= message